# Microsoft Graph /findMeetingTimes empty results: emptySuggestionsReason = "AttendeesUnavailable" or "Unknown"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We use Microsoft Graph to find available slots in the calendars of one or more users of a Microsoft tenant.

Sometimes, for no known reason, we receive empty results with the following `emptySuggestionsReason`:

- `Unknown`
- `AttendeesUnavailable`
  Note that for `AttendeesUnavailable` we checked the calendars of the users and found that they actually had availabilities.

I know that other people have experienced this but didn't find any solution.

**Sample request for attendeesUnavailable**

```
Timestamp: 2021-06-23 12:58:11.124306
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes
Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer <USER_TOKEN>
Body:
    {
                    "timeConstraint": {
                        "activityDomain": "work",
                        "timeslots": [
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-14T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-14T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-14T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-14T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-15T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-15T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-15T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-15T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-16T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-16T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-16T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-16T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-19T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-19T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-19T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-19T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-20T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-20T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-20T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-20T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T16:00:00"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "meetingDuration": "PT0H45M",
                    "isOrganizerOptional": true,
                    "attendees": [
                        {
                            "type": "required",
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "address": "xxx@email.com"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "required",
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "address": "xxx1@email.com"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "required",
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "address": "xxx2@email.com"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "minimumAttendeePercentage": 100
                }

Response:
    {
        "emptySuggestionsReason": "AttendeesUnavailable",
        "@odata": {
            "context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult"
        }
    }
```

**Sample request for Unknown**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes
Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer <USER_TOKEN>
Body:
    {
                    "timeConstraint": {
                        "activityDomain": "work",
                        "timeslots": [
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-21T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-22T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-23T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-26T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-27T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-28T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-29T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-07-30T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-03T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-04T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-05T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-06T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-10T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-11T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-12T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-13T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-13T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-13T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-13T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-16T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-16T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-16T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-16T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-17T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-17T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-17T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-17T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-18T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-18T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-18T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-18T16:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-19T07:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-19T10:00:00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "start": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-19T12:00:00"
                                },
                                "end": {
                                    "timeZone": "UTC",
                                    "dateTime": "2021-08-19T16:00:00"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "meetingDuration": "PT0H30M",
                    "isOrganizerOptional": true,
                    "attendees": [
                        {
                            "type": "required",
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "address": "xxx@email.com"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "minimumAttendeePercentage": 100
                }

Response:
{
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "Unknown",
    "@odata": {
        "context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Unknown` reason, it turns out that the User for whom we were looking for slots had disabled sharing calendar availabilities with other users of the tenant by default. Microsoft Graph sends an Unknown reason for having no slot suggestions in this case.

For the `AttendeesUnavailable` reason, we were unable to reproduce the bug at all, so we're assuming the participants made a mistake when they said they did have an available slot in common.